# Fastboot not working for Kindle Fire HD

Tags: fastboot, amazon-kindle-fire

When ever I try to fastboot my kindle fire HD 7 inch. Running 7.4.3 it does not pick up the device (it is also rooted) when I try the command `fastboot -i 0x1949 getvar product`.

I connect the kindle and it just reboots as it normally would the command window and it still says waiting for device.

I installed the SDK correctly since it allowed me to root my kindle just fine. Do I need another tool or should my kindle not be rooted?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found a solution that worked for me. I hope this helps you too:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2271909&page=9

1. In Windows Device Manager, find Tate-PVT-08 in on the list.
2. Right click, and select Update Driver
3. Select Browse computer for driver software
4. Select Choose from a list of device drivers installed on my computer
5. Find Kindle on the list
6. Accept ADB composite interface

Comment: This is not working for me, I have this same exact model and all I get at the end is code 10 device can't start.